# Real-Statistics Excel Add-on LJUNG formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using `LJUNG` formula from the *[Real-Statistics](https://www.real-statistics.com/)* add-on. The issue is that the formula uses the empty cells in its calculation. Can anyone advise how to exclude empty cells?

```
=LJUNG(AXW3:AXW377)
```

The result for this is 0.000

While the manual highlight of the data specific array `=LJUNG(AXW280:AXW340)`, provides the result of: 0.152.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brilliant answer provided by Jeremy Hodge

```
Sub test(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    
    lastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    For c = 1 To Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        If IsEmpty(sht.Cells(2, c).Value) = False Then
            Set startCell = sht.Cells(2, c)
        Else
            Set startCell = sht.Cells(1, c).End(xlDown)
        End If
            
        Set endCell = sht.Cells(1048576, c).End(xlUp)
        
        sht.Cells(lastRow, c).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & startCell.Address & ":" & endCell.Address & ")"
    Next c
End Sub
```